# min & max value in range in loop

Tags: excel, vba

I've faced huge problem with my macro. I have data that contains colums with quantities and values of stock like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. to go through every row until the very last, locate quantity (colums with Q letter) and values (colums with V letters) below 0, then adding these quantities below zero to the maximum quantity within the row and adding these values  below 0.
2. to find values within age category for every row that have no corresponding quantity  (see cell B4 as example) and add these values to the maximum value within the row.

Comment: I don't follow what it is you are asking

Comment: This is the final output that I extracted from source data. I know that I should apply looping until the last row. The problem is that I don't know how to find in this loop the quantities and values below zero for every row and then add these to maximum value in row. The same goes for 2nd point.

Comment: You say: *I've faced huge problem with my macro.* So, please show the macro as it is so far, so we can advise you how to correct it or otherwise change it. What do you mean with "age category"?

Comment: I wrote macro that copy data from source file and paste it into target file. Next I defined the last row that I assume is useful for the loop but I don’t know how to define such a complex loop (I think that writing two loops is applicable here) and that my code doesn’t include so I’ve not attached it.

Answer (score 0):

Why VBA for something you can achieve with a formula?

Let me show you how I calculate the maximum of a list of cells, referring to a column, whose name starts with a "V":

```
=MAXIFS(A2:F2,A1:F1,"V*")
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Explanation:

- Take the maximum of the values on the second row (A2:F2)
- The criteria you need to take into account refer to the first row (A1:F1)

  - The criteria is that it should start with a "V".

Comment: 1. I want to practice VBA so I've been wonering how to resolve this in VBA.
2. This formula itself doesn't resolve the problem. Although you defined the maximum value in the row that is fine. But when you will have two values below zero I think that defining it by MINIFS function would be of no use since you have to add TWO values below zero to the maximum value within the row.

Comment: as formula just add a ....sumif.... behind the ...maxif... that should work fine. If you want VBA, please show the code you have so far.